# Determine a return value conditional for a discriminated union

Tags: typescript

I want to provide a type for my `getKeyOrName` function. I expect that this function should return `EitherOr['key']` or `EitherOr['name']`. However, when I specify a return type like this, I'm getting a TS error:

> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'EitherOr'.ts(2339).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBnKBvAUFKBlA8gWQFEB9AOQEFCoBeKAIkQHsJgA6EAQ2doBoNt9iASQAimanUbMWASwAmPNAF80AF3gAHYFAAqOEFpoooAawQAuWAmSKA3Ko1btWYAGMGIWeKMdmFxCoAnaRAAcyhbe00oAmkVAAtgAJwA8V19KAAfHWc3Dzs0XP8oaUQ9AygACgYAIwArCxj4xOSASgsa2uLkNIMAPigAclN4AeKQKA60AvcikOAVOHhkkk5yqrqG2ISkgLboreaAgG0hhAGAXUz9pp2Tn2ALzCp+9CgA+bAA8ZKy9dqWqAAfgmdRYwyg7VB9zsiiAA)

```js
enum Keys {
  SOME_NAME = "some.name",
  SOME_ID   = "some.id",
}
type TOne = { key: Keys };
type TSecond = { name: string };
type EitherOr = TOne | TSecond;

const isOne = (obj: EitherOr): obj is TOne => 'key' in obj

const getKeyOrName = (obj: EitherOr): EitherOr['key'] | EitherOr['name'] => {
 return isOne(obj) ? obj.key : obj.name;
}
```

Comment: `Cannot find name 'TMerged'.` - please give a [mre].

Comment: Why not write overloads? Otherwise you'd have to make the _type_ conditional too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you give me an example?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads, https://tsplay.dev/Nro90m

Answer (score 0):

I used `double keyof` to access to needed types

```
enum Keys {
  SOME_NAME = "some.name",
  SOME_ID = "some.id",
}
type TOne = { key: Keys };
type TSecond = { name: string };
type EitherOr = TOne | TSecond;

const isOne = (obj: EitherOr): obj is TOne => 'key' in obj

const getKeyOrName = (obj: EitherOr): keyof keyof EitherOr => {
  return isOne(obj) ? obj.key : obj.name;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBnKBvAUFTUDKB5AsgKID6AcgIJFQC8UARIgPYTAB0IAhi3QDQZZ4ixAJIARLLQbM2ASwAmvfgF9%20AF3gAHYFAAquENtoooAawQAuWAmRKA3Gs3ad2YAGNGIOTVRROLS4iqAE4yIADmUHYOWlCEMqoAFsBBuEHeegZQAD66Lu6e9pj8%20YFQMoj6hlAAFIwARgBWlnGJyakAlJb1DWXIGYYAfFAA5Gbww2UgUN38xR6lYcCqcPCppFxVtY3N8UkpQZ2mCIwAZkfwp7G7bWnUQ%20hYQUtgQVPllVsN7VAA-NONrDGUC6AL8wEKkSAA)

Comment: Do you mind explaining why it works?

Comment: First keyof  takes  `TOne` or `TSecond`. And second keyof takes result from the first: `key` from TOne or `name` from TSecond